# Can I use this method in a MVC Controller ? And how can I call this from ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static object GetBeneficiaryAccount()
{
    ClsBeneficiaries obj = new ClsBeneficiaries();
    var List = new List<ClsBeneficiaries>();
    List = obj.GetAllBeneficiariesAccout();
    var result = List.Select(a => new
    {
        Account_ID = a.Account_ID,
        Name = a.Name,
    });
    return result;
}
```

I m new in mvc. I used this method in my asp application but now I want to learn asp mvc.

So any one can help me that can I use script method in controller and how I call this method from Ajax?

Comment: What's the value of `result`? Is it json?

Comment: Are you wanting to return a partial view or JSON?

Comment: in this situation i return JSON but i want to fill a select from this result..

Comment: are u using asmx service ?

Comment: No i use this web mathod is controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonResult for this.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetBeneficiaryAccount()
{ 
    ClsBeneficiaries obj = new ClsBeneficiaries();
    var List = new List<ClsBeneficiaries>();
    List = obj.GetAllBeneficiariesAccout();
    var result = List.Select(a => new
    {
        Account_ID = a.Account_ID,
        Name = a.Name,
    });

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Asp.Net Asmx Solution

*for this you will need to create an `.asmx` file from add new item menue*  
As far in my knowledge, you are calling the asp.net asmx web services in your mvc project for backward comparability. So, if you really need to call `.asmx` web services from asp.net mvc project here is the step you do. 
First add route entry into your **App_Start -> RouteConfig.cs** file

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");
```

this will to the routing engine in asp.net mvc to ignor path that ends with `.asmx`.

Next, go to your web.config file and the following entry in `System.Web`

```
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Great, now if you call your `.asmx` service from browser (in my case its **webservice1.asmx**),you should see the response like this;
[image]

In case if you are anxious, here is my `WebMethod`

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
```

And now you can test it with jQuery just like regular **Ajax** calls and it should work;

```
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $.get('/webservice1.asmx/HelloWorld', function (data) {
                    alert('');
                    alert(data);
                });
                alert('after');
            });
        </script>
```

And yes, don't be surprise if you see an alert **After** first because its an async call.

#### MVC Solution

You can't invoke WebMethod from Controller. if you need to return json from controller then simply you can decorate your action method by `HttpGet` and return simply `JsonResult`

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetBeneficiaryAccount()
    {
        ClsBeneficiaries obj = new ClsBeneficiaries();
        var List = new List<ClsBeneficiaries>();
        List = obj.GetAllBeneficiariesAccout();
        var result = List.Select(a => new
        {
            Account_ID = a.Account_ID,
            Name = a.Name,
        });

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now, simply you can call it by using jQuery;

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $.get('/YourControllerName/GetBeneficiaryAccount', function (data) {
                alert(data);
                //do something
            });
        });
    </script>
```

As you are new to MVC then i recommend to follow the MVC solution which will simply return a JSON data.